# Is the image in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times}$ of a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ also Cauchy, or even fixed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, p-adic-number-theory

> Is the image in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times}$ of a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ in general, also Cauchy?  Must it be a fixed point?

I'm assuming that it's conventional to consider a sequence to be Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ if it's Cauchy as measured by its p-adic metric.

By the image in $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$ of a number $n$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ I mean $n\times\lvert n\rvert_p$ for example the image of $24$ in $\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times}$ is $3$.

If true, this fact would be helpful.  It looks like it should generally be true but if we consider the sequence:

$2^n\times n\times (2(n\mod 2)+1)$ for increasing integers $n$, i.e. the sequence:

$\{1,6,4,24,16,96,64,\ldots\}$

We can see from the sequence $\lvert n_i-n_{i-1}\rvert_2=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16},\ldots\}$ that it is Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ despite the fact that its image in $\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times}$ is $\{1,3,1,3,1,\ldots\}$ and it would appear on the face of it to have two distinct trajectories.

Now I'm led to believe that the 2-adics are something of a special case when it comes to convergence because uniquely their logarithm has a nontrivial kernel in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-principal units (and let me be clear, I have next to no idea what that means).  The question is, is this independence of convergence in the two components of Cauchy Sequences unique to $\mathbb{Q}_2$ or can this happen for any $p$?

Comment: Won't the nearly same counterexample $a_n=\begin{cases}p^nu&\text{$n$ even}\\p^nv&\text{$n$ odd}\end{cases}$ with $u\ne v$ and $|u|_p=|v|_p=1$ always work?

Comment: $(-p)^k$ is Cauchy, but the image $(-1)^k$ is not. If it is Cauchy in $\mathbb Q_p^{\times}$ and does not converge to $0$ then it has your property.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry I took your comment to mean "If it is Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and does not converge to $0$ then its image in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}^{\times}$ is Cauchy".  Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, I mean "If a sequence is Cauchy in $\mathbb Q_p^{\times}$ and doesn't converge to $0$ in $\mathbb Q_p$ then its image is Cauchy." @RobertFrost

Comment: It does work when $p=2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok thanks I think I get you. By "being Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$", you mean the same thing as "its image is Cauchy?" So we're talking about sequences e.g. whose even factors might go $\{2,4,2,4\ldots\}$ but their odd factors are Cauchy say $\{1,3,7,15,31,\ldots\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no such requirement in any base $p$. Convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and convergence of its image in $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$ can be independent, as demonstrated by:

The Cauchy sequence $(-p)^k$ whose image in $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}:\{-1,+1\}$ does not converge.

And the sequence:

$\{2,12,14,60,62\ldots\}$ which does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ while its image in $\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times}: \{1,3,7,15,31,\ldots\}$ is Cauchy.